# Suppose that $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function satisfying $f'(x)=1/x$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$, show $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I would like to ask you for some help with the following problem.

Suppose that $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function satisfying $f'(x)=1/x$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$, and $f(1)=0$. Show, without using the fact that $f$ must be the natural logarithm, that for all $x,y \in (0,\infty)$, $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$. Hint: fix $y$ and let $g(x)=f(xy)$. Find $g'(x)$.

The furthest I managed to go is to find the $g'(x)=f'(x)$, but I have no idea how to proceed. Have you got any suggestions?